# Generate random numbers with a specific font

Tags: fonts, tables, random-numbers

My objective is to create a table or some form of environment as shown in the figure below.

[image: What I want]

The numbers should be randomly generated every time you compile and have the font shown below.

[image: Number with specific font]

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm quite certain that the digits you show are from the "OCR-A" font. (To be entirely certain, you'd have to show the shape of the digits 5 and 8.) See, e.g., http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:OCR-A_char_digits.svg, for more details.

Comment: Is its(the OCR-A font) implementation in latex possible?

Comment: Yes, with the `ocr` font package. Type `texdoc ocr` on a command line to get more information about this package.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could use TikZ nodes and pgf made random numbers, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,positioning}
\usepackage{datetime}
\pgfmathparse{\year+\time+\currenthour+\currentminute*\currentsecond}
\pgfmathsetseed{\pgfmathresult}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going right,node distance=-0.4pt]
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,15} {
        \node (\x) [draw,on chain=1] {\pgfmathparse{random(0,9)}\ocr{\pgfmathresult}};} 
    \node [above of=1,anchor=south west,yshift=2ex,xshift=-2.4ex]
        {Do not write in this area};
    \node [below of=1,anchor=north west,yshift=-2ex,xshift=-2.4ex]
        {\scshape Each document must have a unique serial number};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output, using `ocr-a` numbers, as Mico advised in his comment below:

[image: random numbers on chain]

To get different numbers for each compilation, you could initialize the random number generator yourself by

```
\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}
```

By default, it's the value of `\time`*`\year`. So it would't change during *each* compilation, so I used the `datetime` package to use also minutes and seconds for calculating the seed. So the random values should change each second. You could also use values or counters in your `.aux` file instead.

You can get the `ocr-a` font from CTAN: http://ctan.org/pkg/ocr-a.
If you don't manage to install it, a quick workaround: you could load the `mf` and `tfm` files (for example from [here](http://slackware.tamu.edu/slackware/slackware-2.1/usr/lib/texmf/fonts/misc/ocr-a/)), put them into your document directory and run (with `fontenc` and `ocr` as above) - it worked for me.

Comment: Can I use the current time to generate a different random number with each compilation?

Comment: You'll also want to add the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr}` in the preamble, and then encase the command that outputs the digits in `\ocr{...}`, to get the displayed numbers to show up in OCR-A.

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen: yes, I extended my answer.

Comment: Hi @StefanKottwitz, I finally got it to work. For some reason or the other, neither of TexWorks or Texmaker were generating the font properly but when I tried to compile with WinEdt, it worked just fine. Don't know what is the problem but hey it worked.

Comment: After a lot of trial and error, finaly it worked (using Texmaker here under Kubuntu 12.04). Key actions: (1) put all ocr-related font files in the same directory as the tex source and (2) comment out the `\pgfmathparse` and `\pgfmathsetseed` commands in the preamble! Don't really understand why.

Answer (score 12):

On the off-chance that you're unable to manage the fonts, you can download the [OCR-A numeral SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:OCR-A_char_digits.svg) and convert it to PDF (say) using [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/). Then, include each numeral via the traditional `\includegraphics` (from [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)) with some appropriate `trim`-and-`clip`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf
%\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx (implicitly loaded by tikz)
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}

% Extract numerals from image
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-0\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=0 0 4990 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-1\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=554 0 4438 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-2\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=1109 0 3882 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-3\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=1664 0 3327 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-4\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=2218 0 2773 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-5\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=2773 0 2218 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-6\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=3327 0 1664 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-7\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=3883 0 1109 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-8\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=4437 0 555 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%
\expandafter\def\csname ocr-a-9\endcsname{\includegraphics[width=2ex,trim=4991 0 0 0,clip]{ocr-a}}%

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=1 going right,node distance=-0.4pt]
  \foreach \x in {1,2,...,15} {
    \node [draw,on chain=1] {\pgfmathparse{random(9)}\csname ocr-a-\pgfmathresult\endcsname};} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the above example there is no need for an explicit loading of `graphicx`, since [`tikz`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) already loads it.

The following steps were following in Inkscape:

1. Open the document:

   [image: Inkscape - open SVG]
2. Save as PDF:

   [image: Inkscape - save as PDF]

Comment: I will give it a try. Is the above image the original svg file or the 800*86 pixels png file?

Comment: @azetina: It is the original SVG (not the PNG). Inkscape handles SVG without problem. My coordinates for `trim` match the original downloaded SVG. If you download the lower resolution PNG, you would need different coordinates.

Comment: @WernerThanks for the quick reply will do the conversion of the image file in a few as soon as Inkscape finishes installing.

Comment: @azetina Can this be considered a "clean" solution? Why is it (so) hard to get `ocr-a` to work?