# How can I install the ocr-a font on MiKTeX 2.9?

Tags: fonts, installing, miktex

In my previous post [Generate random numbers with a specific font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41849/10898)

I was unable to compile the code given in the discussion because there was an error when compiling which said that

```
(C:\Users\azetina\Desktop\Test\testrandomnumbers.aux) ){C:/Program Files/MiKTeX
2.9/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}Trying to make PK font ocr10 at 569 DPI...
Creating ocr10.pk...
Running miktex-mf.exe...
This is METAFONT, Version 2.718281 (MiKTeX 2.9)



! I can't find file `ocr10'.
```

When I try the ocr package without the [ocr-a], the file compiles and even with ocr-b it still compiles. So I am interested in knowing how to install the ocr-a font so that i can compile the document.

Comment: Just checking: Did you click `Refresh FNDB` and `Update Formats` buttons on `Start -> MikTeX 2.9-> Maintenance (admin) -> Options` menu?

Comment: I did all of that but no good results.

Comment: I have found a solution and it is dependent on the compiler. As mentioned in my other post I was trying to use the ocr-a font but it was not working properly. At the time I was compiling using Texworks and Texmaker and non compiled but when I tried WinEdt it suddenly worked. I don't understand why but it gave the results I was looking for. For other users, I downloaded the fonts from ctan and placed them in the same folder the file to compile was.

Comment: Thanks for telling us the solution! As the reason is unclear and the problem vanished somehow, I will close the question.

Comment: Sure no problem

Comment: See [How to install and use the `ocr-a` font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/106402/5764).