# How to install and use the ocr-a font

Tags: fonts, packages, installing

Can someone help to install the [`ocr-a`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ocr-a/) font? I'm using fedora, I'm trying to find a proper tutorial but cannot find a good one.

Comment: See: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ocr-a/

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following should do:

1. Download the zip file http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/ocr-a.zip
2. Unzip it: `unzip ocr-a.zip`
3. Do `cd ocr-a` and edit the `ocr10.mf`, `ocr12.mf` and `ocr16.mf` files so that their last line reads `input ocr-a` instead of `input ocra` (this is a bug in the distribution)
4. Do `cd ..` to get one level up
5. Do the following commands in super user mode (I'll use `sudo`, assuming a Bash shell)

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/source
   sudo mv ocr-a $(kpsewhich -var-value=TEXMFLOCAL)/fonts/source/
   sudo mktexlsr
   ```
6. Try compiling the following plain TeX file (`pdftex tryocra`)

   ```
   %%% File name tryocra.tex
   \font\ocraten=ocr10
   \ocraten

   ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVZ

   \bye
   ```

The result should be as follows

[image]

---

A ZIP file with the fonts converted to Type1 and OpenType, along with a style file for getting them with LaTeX is available [here](http://profs.scienze.univr.it/~gregorio/ocr-a-type1.zip), with instructions for installation on a Unix system with TeX Live.

Comment: But when I need to write one piece of text, should i do it like \ocraten{test} ??

Comment: @user1774937 Do you want to use it in LaTeX?

Comment: Is step 3. in general needed?

Comment: @71GA It's needed in this case because of the mentioned bug.

Comment: Be careful: in MikTex 2.9, the first solution works if you copy the files in the correct folder. It happens for me that even if MikTex is installed in AppData/local/Programs/MikTex2.9, the metafont program was working in AppData/local/MikTex/2.9. When I placed the file over there, it finally work.

Comment: @DenisCousineau I never support MiKTeX on Windows, for character incompatibility. Today I had to plug in a USB key into a Windows computer for printing a file (no other way to access the printer) and finding how to access the file system took me a few minutes. `;-)`

Comment: I followed the first set of instructions, and am able to compile the example plain-TeX document with the alphabet. However, using the `ocr` package or using `\font\ocrten=ocr10` in a LaTeX document, the font only seems to have numerals 0-9 and no letters. Why does this happen?

Comment: @ScottColby `\usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr}` will use the font described here.

Comment: @egreg, that is what I was using, `\usepackage[ocr-a]{ocr} ... \begin{document}\ocrfamily abcdefg123456789 ...` results in `Missing character: There is no a in font ocr10!` etc. for all the letters but none of the numbers.

Comment: @ScottColby I have the same and get no error and no missing character. Maybe you have a wrong version of the fonts?

Comment: :/ this was my fault. My input had lower-case letters, which OCR-B has, but OCR-A doesn't. Changing to upper case made the missing letters appear! Thank you.

Comment: As a quick question: if there is an error in the distribution, why is it not corrected nearly 10 years later?

Comment: @DenisCousineau The author/maintainer should do it, but the last intervention was in 1989. The package has a restrictive licence that doesn't allow replacing an inactive maintainer.