# Installing a handwriting fonts for LaTeX in Ubuntu

Tags: fonts, installing, ubuntu

I am a LaTeX user and I am using it on Linux Ubuntu. In my document I want to use handwriting font described [here](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/la/). So i tried to include it by using:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{la}
\newcommand{\setfont}[2]{{\fontfamily{#1}\selectfont #2}}
```

in my header and then applying the style using:

```
\setfont{la}{blah bleh blah bloh}
```

I got an error that `la.sty` cannot be found. I know that `.sty` is a file that needs to be installed on my PC which runs Ubuntu 12.04. I found all the packages needed on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/la/), but unfortunately I don't know how to install them. Can anyone help?

Comment: Have a look at egreg's answer [How to install and use the ocr-a font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/106404/15717)

Comment: I tried following this tutorial and after compiling i still get the same result. In the link you provided i ignored point 3. where he only fixes the bug. So are any other ideas? I am using **TEXLIVE**.

Comment: [Manual font installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88423/15717). I think you might need update `updmap-sys`

Comment: the link you gives show the directory `http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fundus/la/` - in it you find the file `la.ins`. Download it. Using the command `latex la.ins` then will generate `la.sty` for you.

Comment: I will do this and report back.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the answer how to install the la-font, but maybe it is easier to install another handwriting font: http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schulschriften - it is part of TeXLive.

You can get a la-variant with `\usefont{T1}{wela}{m}{n}`

A MWE (including some other handwriting fonts):

```
\documentclass[english]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/schulschriften
%Lateinische Ausgangsschrift
\usefont{T1}{wela}{m}{n}
Lateinische Ausgangsschrift (wela)
\blindtext


%Deutsche Normschrift
\usefont{T1}{wedn}{m}{n}
Deutsche Normschrift (wedn)
\blindtext

%Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift
\usefont{T1}{weva}{m}{n}
Vereinfachte Ausgangsschrift (weva)
\blindtext

%Schulausgangsschrift 
\usefont{T1}{wesa}{m}{n}
Schulausgangsschrift  (wesa)
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image: Example of some handwriting fonts]